# convert a list to matrix in python

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, graph

I am trying to build a spelling corrector use graph.

step 1: I use some books as corpus and Python networkx package to build a direct graph node is word ,and I add an attribute in this graph for each node called ‘DISTANCE’, represents the distance between two words.

```
 example:
 graph[‘love’][‘you’][‘DISTANCE’] = 37,means, in my corpus，‘love you’ appeals 37 times.
 graph[‘you’][‘love’][‘DISTANCE’] = 39,means, in my corpus，‘you love’ appeals 39 times.
```

Apparently,graph[‘love’][‘you’] and graph[‘you’][‘love’] is different.
My problem is when I finished some operation, I got a list contains list.
Like this, (the length is variable):

```
[

[who,whom,whose],
[are,all,],
[that,than,this]

]
```

Each sub list contain word that could be right one,my problem is I want to convert this list to this.

```
 [
 [who,are,that],
 [who,are,than],
 [who,are,this],
 [who,all,that],
 [who,all,than],
 [who,all,this],
 [whom,are,that],
 [whom,are,than],
 [whom,are,this],
 [whom,all,that],
 [whom,all,than],
 [whom,all,this],
 [whose,are,that],
 [whose,are,than],
 [whose,are,this],
 [whose,all,that],    
 [whose,all,than],
 [whose,all,this],
 ]
```

So I can calculate the DISTANCE, determine the best one.

I am a very new guy in algorithm, Do you know which algorithm can satisfied this request ? And if you have some suggestion could help me to make this spelling corrector more effective please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to do the conversion:

```
from itertools import product

d = [
    ['who','whom','whose'],
    ['are','all'],
    ['that','than','this']
]

print list(product(*d))
```

Formatted output:

```
[
    ('who', 'are', 'that'), 
    ('who', 'are', 'than'), 
    ('who', 'are', 'this'), 
    ('who', 'all', 'that'), 
    ('who', 'all', 'than'), 
    ('who', 'all', 'this'), 
    ('whom', 'are', 'that'), 
    ('whom', 'are', 'than'), 
    ('whom', 'are', 'this'), 
    ('whom', 'all', 'that'), 
    ('whom', 'all', 'than'), 
    ('whom', 'all', 'this'), 
    ('whose', 'are', 'that'),
    ('whose', 'are', 'than'), 
    ('whose', 'are', 'this'), 
    ('whose', 'all', 'that'), 
    ('whose', 'all', 'than'), 
    ('whose', 'all', 'this')
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this function is working so well~